# How do i route between views efficiently using buttons without a nav-bar?

Tags: c#, css, .net

Basically, I've been trying to refer to online guides to get my button to load a different view when I click it but it gives me the error page instead. So far all the guides and forums I've come across have explanations but not ones that I can apply and can fully understand because I am a novice at this.

```
<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
<body style="display:block;background-color:#b1c0d8;margin-top:auto;">
    <div><p style="font-size:20px"> </p></div>
    <div class="div" style="display:block;text-align:center;height:50px;margin:0 auto">
        <a href="~/Home/TestBed.cshtml" class="Button">HQ</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to use instances of the views similar to my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net